# Description on Product page disappears after update to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I recently upgraded Magento core from 1.9.0.0 to 1.9.2 and noted a few changes to the rwd theme. The least welcome of these was that the Description/Additional Information/Reviews section of the Product page disappeared entirely. Was this a deliberate change? Even if it was, how do I get them back? Can anyone help?

UPDATE: After researching adding a block to a page using a local.xml file for something else I was doing, I wondered if I could just add this block back in the same way. Here's what I put in my local.xml:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product_view_description" after="product_view_media" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml" />
        </reference>
     </catalog_product_view>
 </layout>
```

This doesn't work, which probably isn't surprising given that it is the result of a certain amount of guesswork. Am I totally barking up the wrong tree? Or is there a simple error that I could correct to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when I changed `product_view_media` to `product.view.media` the description appeared.

Answer (score 1):

You should also put a

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_view_description') ?>
```

in view.phtml file

Comment: Unnecessary as content is a core/text_list block which renders all its own children.